# Partially labelled open-class classification problem with heavy overlap

Tags: classification, unsupervised-learning, text

Let's say we have a corpus of text, including discussions about movies and about sports. Unsupervised clustering would typically cluster into the two topics of discussion. However, we are interested instead about the authors of the text, who all write about both topics. If we have labels for the topics, is there a way to build an unsupervised system for clustering by author instead, by eliminating features corresponding to the labelled classifications (topics)?

I have looked at this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.08788.pdf, but I am unsure the extent to which the novel (i.e. unlabelled) classes can overlap with the labelled ones, as my understanding of the paper is that it assumes unique classifiers. Similarly, it is not a classic open-class situation because, again, the labelled data overlaps with the authorship.

Answer (score 0):

The topics labels are completely useless for this task since they do not contain any indication about the author.

What we're dealing with is an [authorship attribution](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=authorship+attribution&btnG=) problem, it belongs to the broad family of [stylometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry) methods. More precisely I think this could be quite close to the problem of [style change detection](https://pan.webis.de/clef22/pan22-web/style-change-detection.html), but the exact specification of the problem depends if the texts by the different authors are already provided in separate documents. If separate documents are available, each with a single author, the general [authorship verification](https://pan.webis.de/clef22/pan22-web/author-identification.html) approach can be used.

Imho the main problem in this scenario is that you don't have any labels even for some subset of the data, so you could run some unsupervised system but there's no way to evaluate its results.

Comment: Thanks. I feared as much.

I only considered the use of the topics to help rule out features of style that would group towards either of the topics, since this is a multivariate problem.